# Using Raspberry Pi as a thin client to Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, thin-client, raspberry-pi

I just got a Raspberry Pi and want to try to use it as a thin client to Ubuntu so that I can browse the web and run applications.  What programs do I have to run on the Raspberry Pi to do this?  What about on the server.

Additionally, if I want to run multiple Raspberry Pis do I need a server for each or what way can I make it easier to manage multiple clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a single server for *many* raspberry pi systems and [simple x forwarding set up](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html) (so you'd need X running on the pi). The advantage of this approach is you could run a mix of native and non native applications - with non native applications just being scripts than run `ssh -X software`, with an account on the server per application. If you wanted a full system thin client, then XDMCP would be a better choice.

Setting up raspberry pi systems as [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/) would be more interesting, and [there's already a project to do it](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5603). You'd need a LTSP server for this.